# php zip архивация папок

Tags: php, php7, zip

подскажите, как записывать  файлы в архив? сейчас создает архив с пустыми папкам

```
$file_folder = "/assets/images/products/";
if(extension_loaded('zip'))
    {
        $zip = new ZipArchive(); // подгружаем библиотеку zip
        $zip_name = time().".zip"; // имя файла
        if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
        {

            $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
        }
        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            echo $file;
            $zip->addEmptyDir ($file_folder.$file);
        }
        $zip->close();
        if(file_exists($zip_name))
        {
            // отдаём файл на скачивание
            header('Content-type: application/zip');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
            //readfile($zip_name);
            // удаляем zip файл если он существует
            //unlink($zip_name);
            $zip('/assest/', $zip_name);
            echo $zip_name;
        }
    $zip('/assest/', $zip_name);
    }
```

Comment: phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);  найди Zip  и там включен ли он? enabled

Comment: да он включен, так как архи папок создает, но сами папки без фоток

Comment: а без цикла вручную?

Comment: у Вас `$zip` это экземпляр класса, я что-то не понимаю как тогда это может работать? `$zip('/assest/', $zip_name);`

Comment: "/assets/images/products/";   и  $zip('/assest/'   st ts местами

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что Вы сами добавляете пустые папки:

```
$zip->addEmptyDir ($file_folder.$file);
```

Лучше попробуйте это:

```
$zip->addFile ($file_folder.$file);
```